# Is it possible to initialize an object parameter in a function call?

Tags: c++, object, parameters

I know there's a shorthand for initializing objects like this:

```
Point p = {0, 0} // x = 0, y = 0
```

My question is if it's possible to use this to create an ad-hoc object as a parameter to a function call, without first storing it in a variable? Here's an illustrative exmample showing how I tried to do it, which hopefully gives a better idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
Point p = addPoints(&{1, 2}, &{3, 4}, &{5, 6});
```

Comment: Can you show the signature of `addPoints()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution cannot work. You cannot take the address of a temporary, which `{1, 2}` would produce (if it knew what type to produce in the first place).

The syntax you've used suggests that the parameters of `addPoints` are of type `Point*` (or perhaps `const Point *`)—a pointer to `Point`. If that's the case, one can assume the function actually stores the address somewhere, so it would be a bad idea to pass an address if a temporary anyway.

If you know the function doesn't in fact store the address, and it is under your control, you could change it to take `const Point &` (or just plain `Point`) parameters instead. Then, you could use the uniform initialisation syntax normally (assuming C++11):

```
Point addPoints(const Point &p1, const Point &p2, const Point &p3);

Point p = addPoints({1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6});
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I'm not using C++11, so that would explain why it isn't working.